# Firebase offline unit testing: Could not load the default credentials

Tags: javascript, typescript, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

I am trying to write some unit-tests using the firebase-emulator. No matter what I do, it always gives me this error:

```
Could not load the default credentials. Browse to https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started for more information.
```

### Test

```
describe('Cloud Functions', function() {
    let myFunctions: any, adminInitStub: sinon.SinonStub<[options?: admin.AppOptions, name?: string], admin.app.App>;
    const tester = funcTest();

    before(async () => {
        admin.initializeApp();
        adminInitStub = sinon.stub(admin, "initializeApp");
        myFunctions = await import("../src/index")
    });
  
    after(() => {
        adminInitStub.restore();
        tester.cleanup();
    });

    describe("dbOrderServiceOnCreated", () => {

        it("should add snapshot successfully", async function() {
            const wrapped = tester.wrap(myFunctions.dbOrderServiceOnCreated)
            
            wrapped(serviceOrderSnap)
            this.timeout(0);

            // THIS IS THE PROBLEM
            const value = await admin.firestore().collection(constants.collectionOrdersService).get(); 
            return chai.assert.equal(value.size, 1);
        })
    })
})
```

Comment: Did you ever get to the bottom of this? I can't really help because you didn't include your full code file with the imports.

Comment: @Ravendarksky I somehow fixed this, but I really don't know anymore. I have to look this up.